# Update a widget every second pyqt5

Tags: python, pyqt5, paintevent

i have a question about how to update a paintEvent every second (or more) without erasing it first. it is a widget to show the live CPU usage (not finished just the circular bar that will have a colour for the % used). suggestions on how to improve my code are always welcome too :). PS: code didnt get in to this question correctly if you want a better look just copy paste it from the first enter all the way down

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
import pyautogui
import sys
import psutil

class CPU(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        screenwidth, screenheight = pyautogui.size()
        Systemheight = screenheight * 0.652
        WH = int(Systemheight * 0.32)
        self.setGeometry(0, 0, int(WH+25), int(WH+25))


    def paintEvent(self, event):
        painter = QPainter(self)
        pen = QPen(QColor(50, 225, 255, 200), 12.5)
        pen.setDashPattern([0.001, 1.1])
        painter.setPen(pen)
        screenwidth, screenheight = pyautogui.size()
        Systemheight = screenheight * 0.652
        WH = int(Systemheight * 0.32)

        CPU = psutil.cpu_percent()
        CPUAngle = (CPU / 100) * 5760
        A1 = 0
        A2 = int(CPUAngle)
        A3 = int(CPUAngle + 50)
        A4 = int(5710 - CPUAngle)
        print(CPUAngle)
        painter.drawArc(12.5, 12.5, WH, WH, A1, A2)

        pen = QPen(QColor(30, 75, 255, 75), 12.5)
        pen.setDashPattern([0.001, 1.1])
        painter.setPen(pen)
        painter.drawArc(12.5, 12.5, WH, WH, A3, A4)

        pen = QPen(QColor(0, 0, 0, 0), 12.5)
        painter.setPen(pen)
        painter.drawEllipse(15, 15, int(WH-6.5), int(WH-6.5))



app = QApplication(sys.argv)

window = CPU()
window.show()

sys.exit(app.exec_()
```

image form script running

[image]

Answer (score 3):

paintEvent always cleans up the previous paint.

On the other hand the logic in general is to create a variable that stores the information used for painting and then call the `update()` (or `repaint()`) method so that paintEvent is invoked updating the painting. And since you want the reading to be periodic then you must use a QTimer.

```py
class CPU(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        screenwidth, screenheight = pyautogui.size()
        Systemheight = screenheight * 0.652
        WH = int(Systemheight * 0.32)
        self.setGeometry(0, 0, int(WH + 25), int(WH + 25))

        self._percentage = 0

        timer = QTimer(self, interval=1000, timeout=self.handle_timeout)
        timer.start()
        self.handle_timeout()

    @property
    def percentage(self):
        return self._percentage

    def handle_timeout(self):
        self._percentage = psutil.cpu_percent()
        self.update()

    def paintEvent(self, event):
        painter = QPainter(self)
        pen = QPen(QColor(50, 225, 255, 200), 12.5)
        pen.setDashPattern([0.001, 1.1])
        painter.setPen(pen)
        screenwidth, screenheight = pyautogui.size()
        Systemheight = screenheight * 0.652
        WH = int(Systemheight * 0.32)

        CPUAngle = (self.percentage / 100) * 5760
        A1 = 0
        A2 = int(CPUAngle)
        A3 = int(CPUAngle + 50)
        A4 = int(5710 - CPUAngle)
        print(CPUAngle)
        painter.drawArc(12.5, 12.5, WH, WH, A1, A2)

        pen = QPen(QColor(30, 75, 255, 75), 12.5)
        pen.setDashPattern([0.001, 1.1])
        painter.setPen(pen)
        painter.drawArc(12.5, 12.5, WH, WH, A3, A4)

        pen = QPen(QColor(0, 0, 0, 0), 12.5)
        painter.setPen(pen)
        painter.drawEllipse(15, 15, int(WH - 6.5), int(WH - 6.5))
```

Comment: thx, follow up question: any sugestion so as to not have the overlay (see link/image)

Comment: @ChrisBrocx I don't understand you, what is overlay for you?

Comment: I mean the part in the image where the two arcs cross each other (the dark blue over the light blue)